# How to make wallpaper that changes throughout the day- brightness to be precise

Tags: desktop-background

How to change brightness of wallpapers with time of the day, like the default wallpaper given.

What tutorials suggest is to use a picture slide-show or applications like `F.lux`.

But I want to automate the brightness only of the image based on time, just like the default wallpaper given in Ubuntu.

Comment: yep , I found the xml of the default file, which simply changes 3-5 images with varied brightness, is there any way to change the brightness of  the same image? or should i go for a custom script?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Wherever I've written `USER`, change it to your username (e.g. mine is `tim`)*.

Create a new folder, perhaps in your pictures folder, and navigate to it:

```bash
mkdir /home/$USER/Pictures/Wallpaper
cd /home/$USER/Pictures/Wallpaper
```

make a new file, make it executable, and edit it:

```bash
touch bgchange.sh
chmod +x bgchange.sh
gedit bgchange.sh
```

Add the following to the file (where is says USER below you need to change this to your user):

```bash
#! /bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///home/USER/Pictures/Wallpaper/'$(date +%H)'.png'
```

That will change the image on the hour to an image with the hour name (i.e. at 1pm (13:00) it will change the background to an image called `13.png`.

Now to create the images. Simply run this command:

```bash
for i in {0..23}; do convert -brightness-contrast $(($i*2))x0 image.png $i.png; done
```

You will end up with a series of images, each "2" brighter than the previous. The darkest (original) will be `0.png`, the brightest `23.png`. It will look a little like this:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You may want to rename these to change the order, but *make sure there is an image for every hour (0 to 23)*.

Finally, the script needs to [start at boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/816/186134):

Run this command, and press enter (2 is selected by default):

```bash
crontab -e
```

and add this line:

```bash
0 * * * * /home/USER/Pictures/Wallpaper/bgchange.sh
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, type `Y` and press enter. It will start each time you boot the computer.

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Since you're using cron anyway, why not set it to re-run the script hourly, instead of using a loop with sleep?